# HiveQL: removing periods from strings

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

How do I remove all "." from every row of `col_a` in HiveQL? `col_a` is a string column.

```
SELECT col_a FROM table_1;
1.0.0.240
1.0.0.96
.
.
.
1.0.134.173
```

I've read about `REGEXP_REPLACE` but haven't been able to successfully implement any solutions I've found online. I've also tried:

```
SELECT REPLACE(col_a, '.', '') AS new_col FROM table_a LIMIT 10;
FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid function 'REPLACE'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select translate(col_a, '.', '') from table_1
```

Comment: @Dudu - Isn't replace supported?

Comment: According to JIra it was added to versions 1.3.0 and 2.1.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13063) however according to the version log (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:versions-panel&subset=-1) it seems that 1.3.0 was never released. 2.1.0 seems to be released on 20/Jun/16